# Laravel Horizon giving a 404 on /horizon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I'm trying to use Horizon in local, on my Ubuntu 20.04 / Laravel 7 / PHP 7.4

Install went OK, but when I tried to acc horizon throught http://localhost:8000/horizon, i get a 404.

Quite similar to this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/237)

I tried to clear my routes, checked that my route is present

[image: route list]

```
 php artisan horizon:status
```

Gives me:

```
Horizon is running.
```

I don't know what to do. Any idea ?

Comment: Did u set admin role ? what u have in AppServiceProvider.php  in register method

Comment: Yes, I put my email in the array

Comment: Did you check the laravel log files?

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped command for show just installed Horizon :

```
php artisan route:clear
```